# One liner if - use condition in string

Tags: php

Is there a way to use conditions in string?

```
$x = 'hello';
$y = 'mister'; // is nullable
$z = 'panda';

$msg = $x . ' ' . {($y == 'mister') ? 'dear ' : ' ' } . $z

// Output: hello dear panda
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You have done it right, all you have to do is swap the curly brackets with parenthesis.

Comment: Replace `{}` with `()`.

Comment: or omit them competely

Comment: @GergelyLukacsy,  `{}` should be replaced with `()`, if removed it will return panda as output

Comment: @JigarShah correct, my bad

Answer (score 4):

You should replace the `{}` with `()`. Also, the `()` around the `$y=='mister'` are not needed. You should try to keep those to a (readable) minimum.

```
$msg = $x . ' ' . ($y == 'mister' ? 'dear ' : ' ' ) . $z;
```

Answer (score 4):

for Ternary operator we are not using `{ }` brackets,instead you have to use `( )`.

Replace your code

`$msg = $x . ' ' . {($y == 'mister') ? 'dear ' : ' ' } . $z`

with

`$msg = $x . ' ' . (($y == 'mister') ? 'dear ' : ' ' ) . $z`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `{}` with `()` and it will work:

```
$x = 'hello';
$y = 'mister'; // is nullable
$z = 'panda';
$msg = $x . ' ' . (($y == 'mister') ? 'dear ' : ' ' ) . $z;
echo $msg;
```

Comment: strange,  Your answer is correct so why you down voted

Comment: @JigarShah we will never know)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question well, you do not intend to find out whether you can use a condition inside a string, but you want to assign a value to a string. The value to be assigned depends on a condition, which could be written like

```
$x = 'hello';
$y = 'mister'; // is nullable
$z = 'panda';

$msg = $x . ' ';
if ($y == 'mister') {
    $msg .= $x . 'dear ';
}
$msg .= $z;

// Output: hello dear panda
```

However, this is a bit long and you intended to use the ? operator. The mistake was that you used the curly brackets {}. This is the fix:

```
$x = 'hello';
$y = 'mister'; // is nullable
$z = 'panda';

$msg = $x . ' ' . (($y == 'mister') ? 'dear ' : ' ' ) . $z;

// Output: hello dear panda
```